# React useState boolean issue (functional component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am having trouble with `useState` and state change in a React Functional Component. I am using an imported package called `Menu` that takes a prop called "**isOpen**" - when set to true the Menu (similar to a modal) is displayed.

When I click on the "Close Menu" button that is within the Menu modal, the state for `menuOpen` changes to false - however, **the isOpen prop does not switch from true to false** - and therefore the menu does not close. Or else Am I missing something here?

```
const MenuButton: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false)
  const openMenu = () => {
  setMenuOpen(true)
}

const closeMenu = () => {
  setMenuOpen(false)
}

 return (
 <Menu buttonNode={<Button onClick={openMenu}>Open 
 Menu</Button>} isOpen={menuOpen}>
   <Box>
     <Text>Menu Heading</Text>
     <Button onClick={closeMenu}>Close Menu</Button>
   </Box>
 </Menu>
 )
}
```

Comment: What is the name of the `Menu` package?

Comment: @Mina https://github.com/priceline/design-system/blob/main/packages/menu/src/Menu/Menu.js

Comment: can you console.log in both the functions when click is done. I'm guessing since button is a child component 2 clicks are getting triggered on just button click.

Comment: It is rendering as false :( ... the Menu package uses this Popover component ... maybe there is something in here that is impacting the state? https://github.com/priceline/design-system/blob/main/packages/popover/src/Popover/Popover.js#L46

Comment: I think it's a good idea to mention 'pcln-menu' package in the title of the question to help other developers googling this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a problem with 'pcln-menu' package as it's developers don't use the single source of truth principle when designing component's state.

You should pass menu content as `renderContent` property to obtain `handleClose` callback. Try this:

```
const MenuButton = () => {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const openMenu = () => {
    setMenuOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <Menu
      buttonNode={<Button onClick={openMenu}>Open Menu</Button>}
      isOpen={menuOpen}
      renderContent={({handleClose}) => (
        <Box>
          <Text>Menu Heading</Text>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close Menu</Button>
        </Box>
      )}
    ></Menu>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That solved it!! You're amazing. I could NOT figure this out for the life of me!